# C# Remove a slash from a URL which is stored inside a var

Tags: c#, url

I'm trying to remove a double slash from a string which is stored inside a variable.

I'm receiving the variable in the following way:

```
cService.CreateCommand("create invite")
    .Description("Creates a invite link for the server.")
    .Do(async (e) =>
    {
        var invite = await e.Server.CreateInvite(maxAge: null, maxUses: 25, tempMembership: false, withXkcd: false);
        await e.Channel.SendMessage(invite.Url);
    });
```

But the response inside this variable looks like the following URL:

```
https://discord.gg//rErYPJB
```

Which contains // in the end. But that URL does not exist. One slash has to be removed.

How could I remove one slash without affecting the https:// double slash?

I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do another replace for the https:// double slashes to add that slash again:

```
// replace all double slashes with single slash
string newUrl = invite.Url.Replace("//", "/");
// re-add removed slash for protocol
newUrl = newUrl.Replace(":/", "://");
```

It could also be done with one `Replace()` only, if the domain is always the same and the double slashes always appear at that very same place:

```
// replace double slashes with single slash
string newUrl = invite.Url.Replace("https://discord.gg//", "https://discord.gg/");
```

In any case, use the `newUrl` variable as parameter to `SendMessage()`:

```
await e.Channel.SendMessage(newUrl);
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2f5eaa2183e026068a237f6b78163f3a been testing but couldnt be done this way.

Comment: OK. I was not aware of the fact that `Invite.Url` is a read-only property. To circumvent that, just use another local variable which you then pass as URL to `SendMessage()`. The code example above has been edited to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string invite = "https://discord.gg//rErYPJB";
        int lastIndex = invite.LastIndexOf("//");
        if (lastIndex >= 0)
            invite = invite.Remove(lastIndex, 1);
```

Comment: might want to check if the `lastIndex < 0` though.

Comment: In this case it has "//". So we do not need to check.

Comment: But id did this to be more complete. Thank you.

Comment: `in this case` sounds like you might want to hard code this then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will always have a discord link, if this is true. This will be an easy solution:

```
invite.Remove(19, 1)
```

This will remove the 19th character of the var.

Comment: come on this is highly custom to the specific length of hostname, can't use it with other URL values.

Comment: @d45ndx try to put "" + before the function that recieves the link

Comment: `invite` is the URL string by the way, why call `Remove` on it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Substring` method to get 2 strings:
`https://` and `discord.gg//rErYPJB`.
On the second string you could use the `Replace` and then append both strings back together

Comment: you want to also deal with `http` vs `https` though

Answer (score 0):

errata corridge

```
string invite = "https://discord.gg//rErYPJB//rErYPJB//rErYPJB//rErYPJB//rErYPJB";

Console.WriteLine(
            invite.Substring(0, invite.IndexOf("://")+3) +  
            invite
            .Substring(invite.IndexOf("://") + 3, invite.Length - (invite.IndexOf("://") + 3))
            .Replace("//","/"));
```

Comment: looks wrong, you would then lose the last character of the URL which would make it invalid. besides the `invite` is not a string.